# Android ICS 1x1 widget text label

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-appwidget

I am trying to make a 1x1 widget for ICS, which displays the text label beneath the icon, and uses the device default text style, but am unable to find out how this is done. I know it is possible, as many 1x1 widgets that come stock with the my Galaxy Nexus have this functionality. I don't want to hard-code a textView in the layout file, as doing this will make it look bad on other devices, which may use different fonts and text sizes, etc.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: You should use `android-widget` instead of `widget`. Your question will get the same amount of attention either way, I promise :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood But he seems to be asking about a homescreen widget which is different from the definition given on the android-widget tag (UI element within Android application such as Button, TextView, CheckBox etc)

Comment: Hmm... I guess that's true. But it kind of sounds like the Tag Wiki is the problem... now that ICS has come and gone, don't you think `android-widget` should be used for this purpose? `Button`, `TextView`, etc. should probably be tagged under `View` anyway. Plus, `widget` is pretty general and could apply to a bunch of different things.

Comment: @AlexLockwood I agree. I'll propose an edit to the tag.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Turns out appwidget is actual the tag that is appropriate

Comment: @Tim, huh, interesting... I'll remember that for next time :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get around putting a `TextView` into the layout. What you can do is choose   style for it from one of the built-in android styles. That way it should match all of the other icon/widget labels. Hopefully this will work in other API versions as well but I know that it looks right on my ICS phone. I'm also not sure if the `FrameLayout` is the best thing to use here but I thought I would do a bit of experimenting. The important part is the `TextView` at the end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonimg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/appwidget_dark_bg_clickable"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_dark" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget"
        android:text="@string/widgetlabeldefault" />
</LinearLayout>
```